# The difference between atomic_load and __atomic_load?

Tags: c, atomic

What is the difference between `atomic_load` and `__atomic_load` in C language?

Answer (score 3):

`__atomic_load` is a name of the gcc builtin. `atomic_load` is a standard function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Which should I use?

Comment: @ken Use `atomic_load()`, as it'll work with any compiler that supports C11 atomic types.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will use atomic_load().